# Array List Index 0 size 0 error

Tags: java

I'm making a program of the Card game War and I need the cards to not reappear so I used an Array list. I'm having trouble with this array list as it's supposed to be random and remove the number, but I get the error IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0, Size 0

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();

Integer rand = random.nextInt(values.size()+1); 
Integer cardId = values.get(rand);
values.remove(rand);
```

Answer (score 3):

First add your Card(s) to your values List (e.g. probably not Integer).
What I'm saying is this, you need a deck of cards before you can play.

Answer (score 2):

Your list is empty and you're

1) Trying to retrieve a value

2) Trying to remove a value

Which throws an error because the list is empty.

Sidenote: you can define `rand` and `cardId` as `int`, instead of `Integer`. Autoboxing/unboxing will take care of that for you.

Add values to your list and it will work as expected (and if you change `random.nextInt(values.size()+1)` to `random.nextInt(values.size())`).

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you try to access index 0 of an empty array, as it says. You cannot do this.

Your code has multiple issues.

- You are not actually storing anything in `values`.
- The acceptable range of indexes for `.get()` is 0 to size-1. The return range of `random.nextInt(size+1)` is 0 to size. This can produce out of range index values. Array indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the code for the values in the array...Or add values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first give the List values before you can `get` values

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();

Integer rand = random.nextInt(values.size()+1);
```

Try this to put values

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++){
    values.add(i);
}

Integer rand = random.nextInt(values.size() + 1);
```